# Parallelization of map reduce

Tags: java, mapreduce

I have 2 independent mapreduce jobs in a single java program. How can I make them to run in parallel. 
My system configuration is
Hadoop 2.7.1
3 node
16 physical cores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using [`job.waitForCompletion(true)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#waitForCompletion%28boolean%29) use [`job.submit()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#submit%28%29) method for submitting the job. The later will submit the job and return immediately. The [`job.waitForCompletion(true)`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#waitForCompletion%28boolean%29) submit the job and waits for its completion.

Then you should use the [`isComplete()`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#isComplete%28%29) for checking the completion status of the jobs. Remember this is `non-blocking call`, you might want to put this into a while loop while some sleep time.

```
Job job1 = new Job("Job1");
Job job2 = new Job("job2");
....  // code which configure both the job objects.
//Now submit both the jobs.
job1.submit();
job2.submit();
// Wait for the completion.
while(!job1.isComplete() && !job2.isComplete()) {
     Thread.sleep(10000);
}
```